# How to load class at runtime in android app?

Tags: android

In my android project I've two layouts in that first layout having one button if i click that button I need to display the second layout in the same layout for this I created a view by using `LayoutInflater` and attached it to "Table Layout" which is present in first layout.

Everything should be fine but the corresponding class file for the second layout is not loading. Without loading I'm not able to call events like click and some other loader events so any one help me how can I load the corresponding class file when i click button in first layout?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you mean by class not loading.

If you want some layout objects to be hidden at a particular time, look into the `visibility` parameter in xml or `setVisibility(true/false)` in code.

If you want to display a whole different screen, create a second activity and call it:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CallingActivity.this, ActivityToStart.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: see I've two layouts and i need to display second layout when i click button in first layout and in first layout i'm having a table layout which is used to add second layout view by using layout inflater at runtime, so the associated class for the second layout is not loading (because when i use layout inflater it only loads layouts not class files)

Comment: A class is not loaded, you have to initialize it yourself. YourClass var = new YourClass(args);

Comment: But i can't call activity by using intents I'm calling by using layout.xml so how to call its associate .java file because it only loads layout but if we call based on intent it automatically loads layout also.

Comment: @nag As he Joru said, to use Activity class you must need to start that activity, XML files can be used in any activity by layoutinflater but you can't mix up 2 activity!

Comment: @vikas if you dont mine can you check my code from here http://pastebin.com/3wMi2m90

Comment: @nag You mean to say that. You are able to see itemView in your table.  But you are not able to call onClickListener() because it is declared on different Activity class? Well if so then its obvious. Otherwise you have an option to register the listener again.

Comment: @vikas ya exactly could you please post me some code how can i do this one.

Comment: @vikas Also tell me is it possible to read edittext boxes and radio buttons etc... data when we enter because it is different activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand, but you appear to be trying to achieve an effect like embedding one activity inside another. You may want to look at the android developer docs about the "fragments" API, which is the currently-recommended way of achieving this kind of effect.